# How to make sure a cube at the middle of screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I create a cube by adding six views to a container and setting their layer transforms.I want to add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to control the cube by changing container's sublayerTransform, but I can't make sure the cube rotates around the center.
Here are my codes:

```
    let point = pan.translation(in: actionView)
    let angle = point.x / 200
    let angle2 = -point.y / 200
    var tran = _containView.layer.sublayerTransform
    tran = CATransform3DRotate(tran, angle, 0, 1, 0)
    tran = CATransform3DRotate(tran, angle2, 1, 0, 0)
    _containView.layer.sublayerTransform = tran
    pan.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: actionView)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you include the code to create the cube... then we can copy/paste and help you with your gesture rotation. Or, take a look at this article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/135/how-to-render-uiviews-in-3d-using-catransformlayer ... and see how it's being rotated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.